# Are there Orthodox sources on alternative estimations of the Exodus?

Tags: sources-mekorot, parshanut-torah-comment, history, yetziat-mitzrayim, shemot-exodus

When discussing the Exodus, some academic scholars try to reconcile the Biblical narrative with empirical findings by lowering the estimates for the number of people involved and the grandiosity of the event (for example [Richard Friedman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H-YlzpUhnxQ)).

Are there Orthodox sources that provide a similar approach?

Answer (score 1):

See Joshua Berman's [*Ani Ma'amin.*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1592645380)

(Very broadly, he assumes many numbers as written biblically were not intended literally.)